# Using RxJS partition operator with angular cause an error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Source in ngOnInit hook:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  var routeParameters = zip(
    this._route.parent.paramMap,
    this._route.paramMap
  ).pipe(
    map(([parentMap, currentMap]) => ({ customerID: parentMap.get('id'), siteID: currentMap.get('siteID') })),
    filter(e => !!e.customerID && !!e.siteID)
  );

  const [creating, editing] = routeParameters.pipe(partition(e => e.siteID === 'new'));

  creating.subscribe(e => this._ss.getEditedSite(null, Number(this.customerID)));
  editing.subscribe(e => this._ss.getEditedSite(Number(e.siteID), Number(this.customerID)));
}
```

It works in dev environment, but it shows the following error:

`Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{ customerID: string; siteID: string; }>, [Observable<{ customerID: string; siteID: string; }>, Observable<{ customerID: string; siteID: string; }>]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{ customerID: string; siteID: string; }, unknown>'.
  Type '[Observable<{ customerID: string; siteID: string; }>, Observable<{ customerID: string; siteID: string; }>]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<unknown>'`

Also after `partition` operator the type inference stop working and `creating` & `editing` are `Obserbavle<unknown>`. Moreother, it's impossible to build project for production because of the same reason.

Is there a correct way to use the `partition` operator in the Angular projects?

**UPDATE**

Declaration of the partition from 'rxjs/operators':

```
export declare function partition<T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number) => boolean, thisArg?: any): UnaryFunction<Observable<T>, [Observable<T>, Observable<T>]>;
```

So there is only one correct way to use it:

```
const [creating, editing] = partition(e => e.siteID === 'new')(routeParameters);
```

but a type inferrence still not working, so a compilable source string would be:

```
const [creating, editing] = partition<{ customerID: string, siteID: string }>(e => e.siteID === 'new')(routeParameters);
```

but it's incredible inconvenient. Then I rather write `if-else` into the `subscribe` callback, although it isn't "best practice" reactive way. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most likely importing wrong `partition()`. `partition()` operator is deprecated and it looks like you're importing `partition` from `rxjs` and trying to use it as operator anyway. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/partition.ts#L52

So you should use the following:

```
import { partition } from 'rxjs';

// but not this
import { partition } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then use it like any other Observable creation method:

```
const [creating, editing] = partition(routeParameters, e => e.siteID === 'new');
```

Comment: There isn't `partition` in `rxjs`. Only in `rxjs/operators`

Comment: See this https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/partition and this https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/partition. What RxJS version you have?

Comment: "rxjs": "~6.4.0",

Comment: So you'd have to upgrade to 6.5.0 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#650-2019-04-23

Comment: I've updated to the latest one, and it start working! thanks )